# Objective-C++ file not linking to Cocoa when building library with cmake

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, linker, cmake

I have a file in my API that is objective c++. The library builds fine but when I go to compile an application that uses the library I get linker errors for all my objective-c calls:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::paste()     in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::paste()     in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::paste()     in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::paste()     in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
     (maybe you meant: l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release, l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc )
  "_NSPasteboardTypeString", referenced from:
      agui::OSXClipboard::paste()     in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSArray in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
  "_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
     (maybe you meant: l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release, l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
  "_NSStringPboardType", referenced from:
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
      agui::OSXClipboard::copy(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSPasteboard in libAgui.a(OSXClipboard.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

My goal is not to have to link to cocoa every time I build an app with my gui lib.

Here is the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(agui)

OPTION(WANT_SHARED "Build agui and the backend as a shared library" OFF) 

OPTION(WANT_ALLEGRO5_BACKEND "Build the Allegro 5 backend" ON) 

if(APPLE AND NOT IPHONE)
    set(MACOSX 1)
endif(APPLE AND NOT IPHONE)

if(MACOSX)
ADD_DEFINITIONS("-x objective-c++")
endif(MACOSX)

if(MACOSX)
find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
endif(MACOSX)

set(CLIPBOARD_SOURCE)

if(WIN32)
set(CLIPBOARD_SOURCE src/Agui/Clipboard/WinClipboard.cpp)
endif(WIN32)

if(MACOSX)
set(CLIPBOARD_SOURCE src/Agui/Clipboard/OSXClipboard.mm)
endif(MACOSX)


set(AGUI_SOURCES
    ${CLIPBOARD_SOURCE}
    src/Agui/Clipboard/Clipboard.cpp
    src/Agui/ActionEvent.cpp
    src/Agui/ActionListener.cpp
    src/Agui/BaseTypes.cpp
    src/Agui/BlinkingEvent.cpp
    src/Agui/BorderLayout.cpp
    src/Agui/Color.cpp
    src/Agui/Dimension.cpp
    src/Agui/EmptyWidget.cpp
    src/Agui/EventArgs.cpp
    src/Agui/FlowLayout.cpp
    src/Agui/FocusListener.cpp
    src/Agui/FocusManager.cpp
    src/Agui/Font.cpp
    src/Agui/FontLoader.cpp
    src/Agui/Graphics.cpp
    src/Agui/GridLayout.cpp
    src/Agui/Gui.cpp
    src/Agui/Image.cpp
    src/Agui/ImageLoader.cpp
    src/Agui/Input.cpp
    src/Agui/KeyboardListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Layout.cpp
    src/Agui/MouseListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Point.cpp
    src/Agui/Rectangle.cpp
    src/Agui/ResizableText.cpp
    src/Agui/ResizableBorderLayout.cpp
    src/Agui/SelectionListener.cpp
    src/Agui/TopContainer.cpp
    src/Agui/Widget.cpp
    src/Agui/WidgetListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Button/Button.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Button/ButtonListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/CheckBox/CheckBox.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/CheckBox/CheckBoxListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/DropDown/DropDown.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/DropDown/DropDownListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Frame/Frame.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Frame/FrameListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Label/Label.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Label/LabelListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ListBox/ListBox.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ListBox/ListBoxListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/RadioButton/RadioButton.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/RadioButton/RadioButtonListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/RadioButton/RadioButtonGroup.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ScrollBar/HScrollBar.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ScrollBar/HScrollBarListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ScrollBar/VScrollBar.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ScrollBar/VScrollBarListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/ScrollPane/ScrollPane.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Slider/Slider.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Slider/SliderListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Tab/Tab.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Tab/TabbedPane.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/Tab/TabbedPaneListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/TextBox/TextBox.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/TextBox/TextBoxListener.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/TextBox/ExtendedTextBox.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/TextField/TextField.cpp
    src/Agui/Widgets/TextField/TextFieldListener.cpp
    )

set(ALLEGRO5_BACKEND_SOURCES
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5Font.cpp
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5FontLoader.cpp
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5Graphics.cpp
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5Image.cpp
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5ImageLoader.cpp
    src/Agui/Backends/Allegro5/Allegro5Input.cpp
    )

    include_directories (./include) 
if(WANT_SHARED)
  add_library(agui SHARED ${AGUI_SOURCES})

  if(MACOSX)
  target_link_libraries (agui ${COCOA_LIBRARY})
  endif(MACOSX)

  set_target_properties(agui PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL "AGUI_BUILD")
  if(WANT_ALLEGRO5_BACKEND)
    add_library(agui_allegro5 SHARED ${ALLEGRO5_BACKEND_SOURCES})
  set_target_properties(agui_allegro5 PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL "AGUI_BACKEND_BUILD")
  target_link_libraries (agui_allegro5 agui)
  endif()
else()
  add_library(agui STATIC ${AGUI_SOURCES})

  if(MACOSX)
  target_link_libraries (agui ${COCOA_LIBRARY})
  endif(MACOSX)

    if(WANT_ALLEGRO5_BACKEND)
    add_library(agui_allegro5 STATIC ${ALLEGRO5_BACKEND_SOURCES})
   set_target_properties(agui_allegro5 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "ALLEGRO_STATICLINK")
  endif()
endif()
```

I'm telling cmake to find and link to cocoa but it does not seem to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at <a href="https://github.com/michaeltyson/Commandline-Cocoa/blob/master/runcocoa.sh">this script</a> to learn how you can link a Cocoa app from the command line.

Comment: I need to link it to a static library.

Answer (score 1):

I had linker errors when compiling an objective-c++ app too. I needed to add this to my CMakeLists.txt:

`add_definitions("-x objective-c++") # as you already have
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-framework ServiceManagement -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa")`

Without this, the `__OBJC__` wasn't defined.

Comment: This worked when I used `-ObjC++` instead of `-x objective-c++`, and I plugged those into CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS instead of CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS (since I was building a library).